# Floating Action Menu implementation using Float action button from Android Design Support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, android-design-library

Is there any simple implementation of Floating Action Menu using Floating Action Button from Android Design Support Library ?

Comment: Have a try of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/douo/dfde289778a9b3b6918f). A simple solution.

Comment: @DouO that gist was incredibly helpful, how can I add padding between the menu buttons?

Comment: @douo I tried your solution, but when i show snackbar it appears over the floating action button. I put FloatingActionMenu inside coordinator layout. Still not working.

Comment: Check my answer for a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/38735427/2412582

Answer (score -2):

I Found one here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare
Hope it helps :)

Comment: And where is the floating aciton menu there?

Comment: I posted an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/example-of-using-floatingactionbutton-with-support-library/30584075#30584075)

Comment: this answer is not relevant to the question